# How to view a node.js tmux session's console.log output

Tags: node.js, linux, tmux, console.log

I'm a C, C++ developer, but I also have a side project at work involved using node.js.

I'm working on a linux based system, and running a tmux session of node.js.
How can I view the console.log output?

This is the line:

**tmux new-session -d -s node_session 'node ./server/bin/www'**

(I've tried redirection into file, etc., but didn't succeeded)

Thanks!